# Django rest-auth not logging in from the client side?

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have used django rest-auth for authentication using django rest framework. For client side I have used angular 4 . The login from the api (drf) works fine.
But the login from angular 4 doesnot works in the sense that  other api endpoints is not logged in with the user.

The login works from client side, no error though.. The problem is it does not get logged in in the backend.. What am I doing wrong?

The service of login:
        login(user){

```
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/rest-auth/login/', user)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Response in browser:

```
token:"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJhbSIsImV4cCI6MTUxNTEzNzI1NCwiZW1haWwiOiIiLCJvcmlnX2lhdCI6MTUxNTEzMzY1NH0.SK78-NeP8M1_Ggml8Mu9OecsoXfaMJ-cHugmJfZb-MQ"
user:{pk: 2, username: "ram", email: "", first_name: "", last_name: ""}__proto__:Object
```

Comment: Can you please paste a screenshot of request payload and response of browser?

Comment: I have posted response of browser.. The payload is username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Save the `token` from the login request and use it as an Authorization header to further requests.

```
this.http.get(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
    }
})
```

https://v4.angular.io/api/http/Http#get

Comment: Got the idea and sent the headers with tokens..But when I post data to a url, the error is:403(forbidden).

Answer (score 0):

Your api is working fine and also the purpose of api fulfilled. You got a token in your response. Just save your token in localstorage.

```
localstorage.setItem("token", res.json().token); //may be token at more deep in your response object.
```

Now you need to send token in the header of your every request. For this purpose you should use interceptor. Just create a ts file with name auth-interceptor.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/observable/throw";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<{}>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {

    const token = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`;
    const authRequest = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", token) });
    return next.handle(authRequest).do(event => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        if (event.status === 401) {
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
          this.router.navigate(["/auth/login"]);
        }
      }
    }).catch(response => {
      if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
          localstorage.removeItem("token");
          this.router.navigate(["/auth/login"]);
        }
      }
      return Observable.throw(response);
    });
  }
}
```

You also need to tell angular that you are using interceptor to intercept request. Just paste following code in your app.module.ts providers array:

```
    {
      multi: true,
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
    }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: ok I got the idea.. Thanks ..But where to assign localstorage.setitem?

Comment: You can save your token in service and can also in component. It's your choice.

Comment: Property 'localStorageService' does not exist on type 'AuthInterceptorService'.
?

Comment: I updated my answer. In my project I was using service for interaction with local storage.